# Running angular 1 and angular 4 on same tab

Tags: angular

I have an angularjs 1 app running in port 3020 and angular 4 app in port 4200. Is it possbile to run the angular 4 app(port 4200) within the same tab on clicking a link.

Comment: Please post the code which you have written so far for implementing this feature.

Comment: Also, please clarify. I understood that you wanted to load A1 app, click a link, the page navigates normally (without new tab) to A4 app. The answer down there shows IFrame, which is about simultaneously showing both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Iframe
The HTML  element represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page. In HTML 4.01, a document may contain a head and a body or a head and a frameset, but not both a body and a frameset. However, an  can be used within a normal document body. Each browsing context has its own session history and active document.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe within your angular 4 app, and point that iframe to the new url.

```
<iframe src="https://www.yoursite.com:3020"></iframe>
```

Add some height and width properties to this iframe depending on how much view you want it to cover.

However, are you sure you want to host it on a different port? You could simply place the two angular apps on the same domain-port and easily browse as a same site.

I have two apps that run on angular 1 and angular 4 respectively, and I have hosted them on the same domain, and they communicate perfectly fine.